# Find duplicate vaule in a dictreader file without a loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary

I am still fairly new with Python and I couldn't see if to find a simeple answer, I am sure this is an easy one. I have a csv file with a list of hostnames and IP.  I need to determine if I have a duplicate hostname or IP in the file.  I don't need to correct it or remove the dup, just tell the user they are a dummy and exit.

Normally with VB I would just dump the data into a data table and loop through it, BUT it seems that with the dictreader once you go through it is done and you have to reopen the file. So I was hoping there is a simple way to include this in my validation loop through the file. After the data is validated I open the csv again and an xml file and write it all up. All that works great. I just want to find the dups in the first pass through. I tried using the reader.seek[0] but that apparently isn't part of the dictreader.  I thought about kicking it to a list but then I lose my fieldnames.

```
with open(sys.argv[2], "r") as srcfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(srcfile)
    reader.fieldnames = [header.lower() for header in reader.fieldnames]
    for lines in reader:
        if ip_check(lines["ipaddress"]) is False:
            print lines["ipaddress"] + " is an invalid address in the " + sys.argv[2] \
            + " file."
            sys.exit(1)
        if hostname_check(lines["hostname"]) is False:
            print lines["hostname"] + " is an invalid hostname in the " + \
            sys.argv[2] + "file."
            sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: `lines = list(reader)`. Now `lines` is a list of dicts. You can iterate on it as many times as you want.

Comment: Do you lose the field names. I tried outputting into a list and lost them. The rest of the code relies on them.

Comment: nope, you just have a list of dictionaries instead of an iterator of dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks I used this and the thing below.  Worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have items in a dict you can check if something is already in the dict like so:

```
my_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

if 'a' in my_dict:
    print 'already seen a!'
```

So you'd just check:

```
if new_ip in reader: 
    # do_something
```

Comment: If you go through the reader to see if something is there, it uses up the read just as the for loop does. I have to reopen the file to read it again.

Comment: Why not do the check while you're iterating the first time? Store seen IPs in a list (`seen_ips = []` `seen_ips.append(lines["ipaddress"])`) and you can use the same syntax as above to check if you've already seen it.

Comment: You can also check for duplicates by making a set from a list and checking if the lengths are equal. 
`a = [1, 2, 5, 5] ` 
`b = set(a)` 
`len(a) == len(b) # this is False`

Comment: Thanks. I used a combo of this and the comment above.  Got it sorted out.